# Want to fetch all image name which is uploaded to s3 and process them in Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I am trying to setup AWS Rekognition using lambda so i have created s3 event trigger for each image uploaded to s3 so when a new image uploaded to s3 it will send an SNS notification > SNS will send to SQS > SQS will trigger lambda to process on that image.

MY main question is how i pass the uploaded Object key name to lambda? if anyone knows or having any idea please let me know

Comment: That is included in the encoded SQS-Event.

Answer (score 1):

I'am not sure why you are using SNS and SQS to reach to lambda from S3.

You can directly link S3 event to Lambda.You can filter the event to PUT/POST/DEL etc too.This is best approach, instead of using SNS and SQS in between.

S3 event pretty much has all the data required  to process.

You may look at
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html